# Spinner, step, count value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I've used jQuery-UI (1.9.2) and create some calculating functions.
Bind them on select inputs, and you can see how it work here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpjCy/2/)

I don't know how to make similar calculation function with "spinner".
For example one step should be equal to (**x**)$;

```
<input type="spinner" class="spinner"
       value="0"
       max="10" 
       min="0" 
       data-fieldname="spinner_count" 
       data-days="13" 
       data-price="22">
```

For now i have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Strix/BQjPm/

Comment: I am very confused by your question... what do you mean by "spinner step count"? What exactly are you trying to do? Also your implementation of [jQuery's Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) is ***way*** off.  `Input` does not have a "spinner" type: here is a [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-type) of `input` types. Perhaps you want an [`<input type="range"/>`](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/BQjPm/1/)? Please clarify.

Comment: Hey! I mean that's 1-step of spinner click have for example price 2$ so if we have max count of spinner "10". Then spinner steps-count = 10==20$. type of spinner "ahah ups" my foult=) sry.
http://jsfiddle.net/Strix/fgCfN/ what i need, but now my spinner is broken need to click 11 times to get value of 10 and some bug when spinn dow and when i click my data-price is refresh....
i've don't know Jquery well to make this arghhhhh =(((((

Comment: We fix some troubles with my friend :
now look's http://jsfiddle.net/Strix/Tm5Ns/